# Select last 20 rows from SQL ordered ASC

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically my whole question is the title. Not really much to describe. I just want to select the last 20 rows from SQL ordered asc.

This doesn't work as expected

```
SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 20
```

It returns the **first** 20 rows in ascending order, but I want **last** 20 rows in ascending order.

Any help much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

What if my sql looks like this?

```
SELECT username, text, date FROM chat ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Tag the dbms used. `LIMIT` is product specific,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to write a query which gives the 20 records you want.  This would be a query in *descending* order by `id`.  Then, you can wrap this in a subquery and select out while ordering in *ascending* order by the `id`.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM chat
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 20
) t
ORDER BY t.id ASC
```

Here is a working Fiddle which you can try:

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Now how to do it if my SQL looks like this? if I just select * from (continue my sql) it throws Error... Why?

my current SQL : SELECT username, text, date FROM chat ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 20

Comment: @StevenDropper Sorry, I should have written `SELECT t.* FROM (SELECT * ...) t ORDER BY t.ASC` ... you probably need to use the alias in the outer `SELECT`.

Comment: Could you take a look on updated question please?

Comment: @StevenDropper Try using the Fiddle I added.  I had a few typos in my query, this is probably why it wasn't working for you at first.  You can either try my answer or follow the duplicate link, but no new answers can be made here because your question has been closed.

Comment: Yeah I noticed. But It doesn't seem to work even on the fiddle as Im trying. Could you try to use my current query from the updated question? I can't really make it work

Comment: Your particular query won't change my answer (or really even the Fiddle).  If you can give me specific error feedback, I might be able to help, otherwise just keep playing around with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115746/discussion-between-steven-dropper-and-tim-biegeleisen).